# OpenVPN using TAP with a dummy interface

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have a dream compute instance that only has one network adapter and it has a public IP address. I am attempting to run OpenVPN with the TAP interface bridged to a dummy interface in order to access the instance from home/work/etc securely. Also as an added benefit I want all connected clients to be able to talk to each other.

The client can ping the server and vice versa as well get to sites on the internet. However, I cannot access any of my services running on the instance (apache, pure-ftpd, samba, git, etc.) I have set 192.168.2.1 as a listening address on apache2 and restarted the server after the vpn connection is established but still no luck.

What am I missing?

Here are my details:

```
eth0 is the interface with the public IP
Dummy interface: eth10:0
OpenVPN IP 192.168.2.1
OpenVPN DHCP IP's 192.168.2.200 - 192.168.2.254
208.xxx.xxx.1 in the openvpn config file is my public gateway on eth0
```

The Process:

I load my modules:

> ```
> modprobe dummy
> modprobe bridge
> modprobe br_netfilter
> modprobe tun
> ```

Setup forwarding thru sysctl:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

On the server I create a dummy interface as follows:

```
ip link set name eth10 dev dummy0
ifconfig eth10 hw ether 00:22:22:ff:ff:ff
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 brd + dev eth10 label eth10:0
```

Then I start the bridge:

```
 # start bridge
 brctl addbr br0
 brctl addif br0 eth10:0
 brctl setageing br0 0 # for vmware?

 # start OpenVPN
 /etc/init.d/openvpn start

 tap="tap0"

 # add tap to bridge
 for t in $tap; do
     brctl addif br0 $t
 done

 # bring taps up and allow access
 for t in $tap; do
     ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
     iptables -A INPUT -i $t -j ACCEPT
 done

 # bring bridge up and assign internal IP
 ifconfig br0 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.2.255

 # allow NAT
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

OpenVPN has the following config:

> ```
> port 1194
> proto udp
> dev tap
> ca ca.crt
> cert server.crt
> key server.key
> dh dh.pem
> auth SHA512
> tls-auth ta.key 0
> topology subnet
> server-bridge 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.200 192.168.2.254
> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
> push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
> push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
> push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
> client-to-client
> keepalive 10 120
> cipher AES-256-CBC
> comp-lzo
> user nobody
> group nogroup
> persist-key
> persist-tun
> status openvpn-status.log
> verb 3
> crl-verify crl.pem
> mssfix
>
> #set the WINS server (SAMBA)
> push "dhcp-option WINS 192.168.2.1"
>
> #For windows, to make the network recognized
> push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 208.xxx.xxx.1"
> cipher AES-256-CBC
> auth SHA512
> ```

OpenVPN Log lines below:

> Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to
>   server... 
>   Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN
>   service... Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
>   Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby ovpn-server[25518]: OpenVPN 2.4.0
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11]
>   [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 18 2017 Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25518]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO
>   2.08 Jun 30 09:37:47 pubby systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server. Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: NOTE: when bridging
>   your LAN adapter with the TAP adapter, note that the new bridge
>   adapter will often take on its own IP address that is different from
>   what the LAN adapter was previously set to Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key Jun
>   30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: Outgoing Control Channel
>   Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC
>   authentication Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: Incoming
>   Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512'
>   for HMAC authentication Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   TUN/TAP device tap0 opened Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100 Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using
>   AF_INET Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: Socket Buffers:
>   R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992] Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
>   Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: UDPv4 link remote:
>   [AF_UNSPEC] Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: GID set to
>   nogroup Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: UID set to nobody
>   Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: MULTI: multi_init called,
>   r=256 v=256 Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: IFCONFIG POOL:
>   base=192.168.2.200 size=55, ipv6=0 Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: ifconfig_pool_read(), in='t430,192.168.2.200',
>   TODO: IPv6 Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: succeeded ->
>   ifconfig_pool_set() Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: IFCONFIG
>   POOL LIST Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: t430,192.168.2.200
>   Jun 30 09:37:48 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: Initialization Sequence
>   Completed Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 VERIFY OK: depth=0,
>   CN=t430 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841
>   peer info: IV_VER=2.4.0 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_PLAT=linux Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_PROTO=2 Jun 30
>   09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info:
>   IV_NCP=2 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841
>   peer info: IV_LZ4=1 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_LZ4v2=1 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_LZO=1 Jun 30
>   09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info:
>   IV_COMP_STUB=1 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]:
>   73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_COMP_STUBv2=1 Jun 30 09:37:56 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 peer info: IV_TCPNL=1 Jun 30
>   09:37:57 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 Control
>   Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048
>   bit RSA Jun 30 09:37:57 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: 73.81.xxx.xxx:43841
>   [t430] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 Jun
>   30 09:37:57 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841
>   MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=192.168.2.200, IPv6=(Not enabled) Jun 30
>   09:37:58 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 PUSH:
>   Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST' Jun 30 09:37:58 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 SENT CONTROL [t430]:
>   'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS
>   8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,dhcp-option WINS 192.168.2.1,route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 208.xxx.xxx.1,route-gateway 192.168.2.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 192.168.2.200 255.255.255.0,peer-id
>   0,cipher AES-256-GCM' (status=1) Jun 30 09:37:58 pubby
>   ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 Data Channel Encrypt:
>   Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key Jun 30 09:37:58
>   pubby ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 Data Channel
>   Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key Jun 30
>   09:37:58 pubby ovpn-server[25524]: t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841 MULTI:
>   Learn: 92:34:xx:xx:xx:xx -> t430/73.81.xxx.xxx:43841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ICMP works but not TCP it almost always comes down to a firewall issue. Verify that your server's iptables are in order.

Comment: I set tap0 in my firewall allow rules instead of br0. `ufw allow in on br0 to any port 80` worked.